# Getting maximum update depth exceeded even when using useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code, I am still getting maximum update depth exceeded even though I have memoized my prop function. Why am I getting this  ? And how should i fix it ? I am trying to dynamically create a list of child components to take some input in. The idea is to be able to add or remove said child components from the parent one and then do some processing on the user inputs

```
const RatingBracket = (props) => {
    const [range, setRange] = useState([])
    const [prices, setPrices] = useState({})

    const {target} = props

    const updatePrice = useCallback((selectedRating, price) => {
        const new_prices = { ...prices, [selectedRating]: price }
        setPrices(new_prices)
      }, [prices]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(target){
            const new_range = [
                Number(target) + 1,
                Number(target) - 1
            ]
            setRange(new_range)
            console.log(new_range)
        }
    }, [target])

    return (
        <div className='rating-bracket-container'>
            {target}
            Player ratings to try
            {range.map(rating=>(
                // <></>
                <InputRow target={rating} updatePrice={updatePrice}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const InputRow = (props) => {

    const {updatePrice, target} = props;
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(target)
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0)

    useEffect(()=>{
        updatePrice({rating,price})
    }, [rating, price, updatePrice])

    return (
        <div className="input-row-container">
            Rating:
            <input value={rating} onChange={(e)=>setRating(e.target.value)} type="number"/>
            Price:
            <input value={price} onChange={(e)=>setPrice(e.target.value)} type="number"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You call `setPrices` in the callback, so then `prices` changes next render, which calls the callback again which calls `setPrices` again and so on...

Comment: @caTS that's not strictly true - all we know is that when `setPrices` is *called*, the function value of that callback is updated. And this will in turn rerender `InputRow`. We can't see what `InputRow` does - if that calls `updatePrice` on render then this would cause an infinite rerender loop, but we certainly can't know for sure with this code.

Comment: I have added InputRow in the same file if you scroll down

Comment: How would I overcome this though ? I need to update the state in my parent component based on what input is there in the child components. I need to mantain all the different inputs in the child inside the parent

Comment: Can you make a code pen of this? I suspect the problem may have to do with the fact that `prices` is an object and `prices` is also a dependency of `updatePrice`. In Javascript, two objects are never equal even if they have the same properties (or lack thereof) because they point to different locations in memory. Therefore, this call will always trigger.

Comment: I have made a codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-brook-ds1q0g?file=/src/RatingBracket.js

Comment: Yes but I need to update prices in the parent ( which has to be an object ) from inputs collected from multiple children. I feel like that is not a unique use case

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem is exactly as was already conjectured in the comments (before we could see `InputRow`).

I'll first explain why you were getting infinite rerenders, then show you a very simple way to adjust your code to avoid this.

The key bits of code that give rise to the problem are as follows.

1 - the `useCallback` that defines `updatePrice` in the parent component:

```
const updatePrice = useCallback((selectedRating, price) => {
  const new_prices = { ...prices, [selectedRating]: price }
  setPrices(new_prices)
}, [prices]);
```

2 - the passing of `updatePrice` to the child as a prop:

```
<InputRow target={rating} updatePrice={updatePrice}/>
```

3 - the `useEffect` in the child that calls this function (note that this runs after the first render, and after every subsequent render that changes any of the dependencies, one of which is `updatePrice`):

```
useEffect(()=>{
    updatePrice({rating,price})
}, [rating, price, updatePrice])
```

So the following things happen when your parent component is first rendered (I'll talk about it as if there is just one `InputRow` child rendered, when in fact there are likely several - this doesn't change any of the points I'm making):

1. the `useEffect` in the child fires, because it always does after the first render. This calls the `updatePrice` function in the parent component.  (PS: you probably need to call it as `updatePrice(rating, price)` instead of `updatePrice({rating,price})` as you currently are.)
2. this function calls `setPrices`, which updates its own `prices` state.
3. because `prices` is in the dependency array of the `useCallback` that defines `updatePrice`, that function changes identity (becomes a new function reference)
4. because its `updatePrice` prop has changed identity, the child component rerenders
5. and because it's `updatePrice` in particular that has changed, which is (correctly!) in the dependency array for the `useEffect` highlighted at 3 above, that effect runs again and `updatePrice` is called

And we now repeat from 1), resulting in an infinite rerender cycle.

Although I'm not entirely sure what behaviour you need to implement here - which I would need to know if there was no simple solution to this problem - in this case there is a straightforward way of rewriting your code that breaks the cycle. It is the definition of `updatePrice` in the parent component, and how it sets the state (definition repeated below for ease of reference):

```
const updatePrice = useCallback((selectedRating, price) => {
  const new_prices = { ...prices, [selectedRating]: price }
  setPrices(new_prices)
}, [prices]);
```

While it's correct to have `prices` in the dependency array here, since the function definition as currently written depends on it - it doesn't "really" depend on it. It only needs to know the current `prices` state to set a new value that's calculated from it (as well as from the function arguments). There is an alternative way to write a state updating function in this case - [with a function argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) that describes how to get from the old to the new state. In your case that would give you:

```
const updatePrice = useCallback((selectedRating, price) => {
  setPrices(old_prices => ({ ...old_prices, [selectedRating]: price }));
}, []);
```

As well as rewriting the function body, I've also removed `prices` from the dependency array - because that's the crucial point here. Your function no longer mentions `prices` at all, so there's no need whatsoever to have it as a dependency. And without that dependency, you'll be free of your infinite render cycle, because now calling `updatePrices` from the child component doesn't cause a rerender of the child. It updates the prices in the parent, as presumably intended, but this no longer alters the identity of the `updatePrice` function itself, so there will be no rerender of the child.

If you've got a long time for a "deep dive" into React and the new ways of thinking with Hooks, I highly recommend [this blog post from Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), which despite the title referring just to `useEffect`, covers a lot of these things, including the use as I've done here of the "functional update" from of `setState` to avoid unnecessary dependencies, and goes further into more complex cases where the solution is to use `useReducer` rather than `useState`. Highly recommended, but not strictly necessary to answer your question - I hope my answer helps by itself [:)]